# No output and crash for simple program.What is wrong with my solution?

Tags: c++, string

Problem-http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=12863&rd=15710

The program is not returning the required value even though the required values are being assigned to the variable 'output' which is being returned.The value being returned is probably a junk value.What is wrong with my solution?

My solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class ErasingCharacters
{
    public:

        string simulate(string s)
        {
            string output;
            int i,j=0;

            for(i=0;i<s.size()-1;i++) //2 simultaneous same characters are not omitted.
            {
                if(s[i]!=s[i+1])
                {
                    output[j]=s[i];
                    j++;
                }

                else
                i++;            
            }

            int n;

            n=s.size();

            if(s[n-1]!=s[n-2]); //Including the last character(If it is not to be omitted.).
            output[j]=s[n-1];

            return output;
        }
};

int main()
{
    string input,output1;
    ErasingCharacters o;

    cin>>input;

    output1=o.simulate(input);

    cout<<endl<<output1;
}
```

Comment: Note that even after fixing the immediate problem, the algorithm doesn't produce the requested result. You have written something similar to `std::unique()` but this isn't was is being asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You didn't actually give your string any size.**

Assigning characters to the string, without making the string big enough, is undefined. You're presently simply overwriting memory that isn't yours, as if you were accessing array elements out-of-bounds.

This is in contrast to languages like PHP which will automatically make room for them.

Instead of `string[j] = s[i]`, use `string.push_back(s[i])`.

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/

Answer (score 3):

The size of a default constructed `std::string` is 0. If you access an element of a `std::string` which is bigger or equal to the `std::string`'s size you have undefined behavior. You should probably use `std::string::push_back()` to construct the result.